# Checkbox in SQL Server Reporting Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I have a report (.rdlc file). I want it to have some live checkboxes NOT images. I have implemented image idea in another report. But in this report, I need live checkboxes that can be clicked just like actual checkboxes.

If anyone have any idea, please do share that how to insert clickable checkboxes in SSRS. I'll be thankful to him/her.

**UPDATE:** I have nothing to do with those checkboxes i.e. I don't have to perform any operation against those checkboxes. I just have to display them so that user can check his desired options and leave the other blank.

Comment: You can't.  SSRS is a reporting application / system, not a GUI.  I know for sure that you can't do this in SSRS 2005, I could be incorrect with newer versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds a wee bit complicated! I am not sure that using reporting services is the best solution for this type of user interactivity. That being said, you could set up a multivalue parameter that's data source is the same as your actual report.

Within your report, you could then check if that row's item within the multivalue parameter is "checked" and display the cell as checked or unchecked. Next you would then need to set up a navigation link in your report that would open the same report with the new/updated parameter values.

I don't know how you are hosting your SSRS reports, so I don't know if you can utilize the navigation links feature. I have never done this type of thing though.

Comment: I don't have to do anything with value inside checkbox

Comment: But you want the user to be able to check or uncheck the box right? what I am saying is you will handle the "checkbox" as an image, and render it based upon the multivalue parameter. when the user "checks" the box by clicking on the image, you fire off the report using the same parameters you have currently, plus the new selected item in the multi value parameter. Let me know if you need any further clarification.